# jQuery: Dropdown list doesn't work on click after changing from .live() vs .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, rss, yql

I am using a jQuery rss widget from **[this page](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/feed-widget-jquery-css-yql/)**. It doesn't work in jQuery 1.9 as it shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live':

$('.dropDownList div').live('click',function(){
```

Using `.live` instead of `.on`, it manages to pull the first feed but the selection doesn't work on click.You can compare these two fiddles: [(.on)](http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1030/) and [(.live)](http://jsfiddle.net/2rLM9/2/). Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Old Code:

```
var tabs = {
    "Google" : {
        "feed"      : "https://news.google.com/?output=rss",
        "function"  : rss
    },

    "Latest Tutorials": {
        "feed"      : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Tutorialzine",
        "function"  : rss
    },


}

var totalTabs;
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    /* Counting the tabs */
    totalTabs=0;
    $.each(tabs,function(){totalTabs++;})


    $('#feedWidget').show().mouseleave(function(){

        /* If the cursor left the widet, hide the drop down list: */
        $('.dropDownList').remove();
        $('#activeTab').removeClass('hover');

    }).mouseenter(function(){

        if(totalTabs>1) $('#activeTab').addClass('hover');

    });

    $('#activeTab').click(showDropDown);

    /* Using the live method to bind an event, because the .dropDownList does not exist yet: */
    $('.dropDownList div').live('click',function(){

        /* Calling the showDropDown function, when the drop down is already shown, will hide it: */
        showDropDown();
        showTab($(this).text());
    });


    /* Showing one of the tabs on load: */
    showTab('Google');

});


function showTab(key)
{
    var obj = tabs[key];
    if(!obj) return false;

    var stage = $('#tabContent');

    /* Forming the query: */
    var query = "select * from feed where url='"+obj.feed+"' LIMIT 5";

    /* Forming the URL to YQL: */
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+encodeURIComponent(query)+"&format=json&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){

        stage.empty();

        /* item exists in RSS and entry in ATOM feeds: */
        $.each(data.query.results.item || data.query.results.entry,function(){
            try{
                /* Trying to call the user provided function, "this" the rest of the feed data: */
                stage.append(obj['function'](this));

            }
            catch(e){
                /* Notifying users if there are any problems with their handler functions: */
                var f_name =obj['function'].toString().match(/function\s+(\w+)\(/i);
                if(f_name) f_name = f_name[1];

                stage.append('<div>There is a problem with your '+f_name+ ' function</div>');
                return false;
            }
        })
    });

    $('#activeTab').text(key);
}

function showDropDown()
{
    if(totalTabs<2) return false;

    if($('#feedWidget .dropDownList').length)
    {
        /* If the drop down is already shown, hide it: */
        $('.dropDownList').slideUp('fast',function(){ $(this).remove(); })
        return false;
    }

    var activeTab = $('#activeTab');

    var offsetTop = (activeTab.offset().top - $('#feedWidget').offset().top )+activeTab.outerHeight() - 5;

    /* Creating the drop down div on the fly: */
    var dropDown = $('<div>').addClass('dropDownList').css({

            'top'   : offsetTop,
            'width' : activeTab.width()

    }).hide().appendTo('#feedWidget')

    $.each(tabs,function(j){
        /* Populating the div with the tabs that are not currently shown: */
        if(j==activeTab.text()) return true;

            $('<div>').text(j).appendTo(dropDown);
    })

    dropDown.slideDown('fast');
}

function twitter(item)
{
    /* Formats the tweets, by turning hashtags, mentions an URLS into proper hyperlinks: */
    return $('<div>').html(
            formatString(item.description || item.title)+
            ' <a href="'+(item.link || item.origLink)+'" target="_blank">[tweet]</a>'
    );
}

function rss(item)
{
    return $('<div>').html(
            formatString(item.title.content || item.title)+
            ' <a href="'+(item.origLink || item.link[0].href || item.link)+'" target="_blank">[read]</a>'
    );
}

function buzz(item)
{
    return $('<div>').html(
            formatString(item.content[0].content || item.title.content || item.title)+
            ' <a href="'+(item.origLink || item.link[0].href || item.link)+'" target="_blank">[read]</a>'
    );
}

function formatString(str)
{
    /* This function was taken from our Twitter Ticker tutorial - http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/jquery-twitter-ticker/ */
    str = str.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig,'');
    str=' '+str;
    str = str.replace(/((ftp|https?):\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/gm,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
    str = str.replace(/([^\w])\@([\w\-]+)/gm,'$1@<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    str = str.replace(/([^\w])\#([\w\-]+)/gm,'$1<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Both fiddles work fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can't just change `.live()` to `.on()` and have it work, the arguments to the function are a bit different.  Check the documentation for [.live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) for instructions on how to convert them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I Fixed it after reading the document [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1033/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.on won't work off the bat because the element isn't created yet.

Replace

```
$('.dropDownList').on('click','div',function(){
```

With

```
$(document).on('click','.dropDownList div',function(){
```